# This account is not eligible for Developer Profiles

Tags: google-account, google-developers

When I go to https://developers.google.com/profile/u/me, I'm prompted to make a profile:

[image: Welcome to Google Developer Profile]

Then when I click the "Create a profile" button, I'm greeted with the message:

> This account is not eligible for Developer Profiles.

[image: This account is not eligible for Developer Profiles]

When I click the "Learn more" I get directed to a help section headed with:

> I’m unable to create a profile with my G Suite account. Why is that?

but I don't have a G Suite account. I have a regular Google/Gmail account.

How can I create my Developer Profile?

Comment: I still have the same problem and can not save the learning path and page to my google developer profile. It used to work at IO 2021.

Comment: The same error to save a page or start pathway to my google developer profile happens only with the chrome browser. Wenn I switch to e.g. safari and this works fine. Do you use chrome? Can you switch to a different browser?

Comment: @YingdingWang I use Firefox, and it works currently. No idea what happened. It works on Chromium as well.